# How to loop over array created by explode()?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, explode

I have a string with multiple values that are separated with a comma. If I use explode to separate these values as follows, how can I create a foreach loop to do something with each of them? Specifically I would like to create a link / anchor tag for each of them.

**My explode statement:**

```
<?php $separated = explode(",", $myString); ?>
```

**Example string:**

```
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this

```
$separated = explode(',', $myString);

foreach ($separated as $value) {
    echo $value;

    // In order to display them in uppercase,
    // just do echo strtoupper($value);
}
```